# Is D3 Force Layout the best option for this graph?

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, force-layout

I would like to create a D3 graph like the image in this post.

Force Layout seem to be the best option, but, my nodes has to have different distances, and each node has to have different size.

So, should I insist on Force Layout?

I couldn't find any example similar to my problem, and it's being very hard to understand how to write down some code to implement those different distances and sizes.

The graph I want to make (it's my first question, so I don't have reputation to put an image directly in this post):

https://i.ibb.co/Tk0hHkv/toaskd3.png

Comment: You can set specific sizes for the nodes and specific lengths for the edges (the links), that's not a problem... however, you cannot set the specific **positions** of those nodes: they are calculated dynamically, based on the node sizes and the edge lengths (that you set previously). Therefore, if *position* is also something that you want to control precisely, a force-directed is not the best option for you.

Comment: force layout assumes forces applied on datapoints depending on different criteria. Do you need this graph to be dynamic? For static one it would be enough to create d3.tree or d3.cluster layout...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different link distances and different radii can be achieved in d3js.

You can add a radius property to each node, i.e. your nodes should look something like `{r:5, id:1, ...}`. Then, when its time to create corresponding `svg` elements, you can do something like

```
var circles = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle").data(nodes);
circles.enter().append("circle").attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; });
```

Similarly, you can add a `dist` property to each of your links. Then add a link force to your simulation like this:

```
var sim = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
  .force("link", d3.forceLink(links)
              .distance(function(l){
                return l.dist;
              })
              .strength(1)
  );
```

For a working example, you can check [this](https://codepen.io/mrpandey/pen/ydzxgz) codepen I just created. You can always check the official [API reference](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/tree/v1.2.1) for detailed information.

In my opinion, D3's force layout is a very flexible option for depicting graphs.